# Magento 1.7.0.2: sql installer show error

Tags: magento-1.7, error, sql

I have create an extension ,which has a `sql Installer`,When i  am trying to  run  that extension,`the installer show  Error`

```
`a:5:{i:0;s:329:"Error in file: "/home/wwww/uat/app/code/local/Amit/Myoptimization/sql/myoptimization_setup/install-1.0.0.php"` - 

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1";i:1;s:925:"#0 /home/seventy/www/uat/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/www/uat/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.0.0')
```

Here the details of extension....

Amit>Myoptimization>etc>Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Myoptimization>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Myoptimization>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <myoptimization_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Amit_Myoptimization</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </myoptimization_setup>
            <myoptimization_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </myoptimization_read>
            <myoptimization_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </myoptimization_write>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <global>
        <models>
            <myoptimization>
                <class>Amit_Myoptimization_Model</class>
            </myoptimization>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <myoptimization>
                <class>Amit_Myoptimization_Block</class>
            </myoptimization>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <!-- start of rewrite class -->
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product>Amit_Myoptimization_Model_Catalog_Product</product>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

SQL Installer:
local\Amit\Myoptimization\sql\myoptimization_setup\install-1.0.0.php

```
<?php
installer=$this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE my_ibanner_banner ADD INDEX  banner_id");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE colorswatches ADD INDEX option_id");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE colorswatches ADD INDEX colorswatches_id ");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE color_relationship_product  ADD INDEX color_relationship_product");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Module File:
XMl File:

app/etc/modules/Amit_Myoptimization.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Myoptimization>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Amitt_Myoptimization>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Can any one tell me ,what are the issue??

Comment: Did you actually solve your problem? If so, please add your solution and accept it to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your have a typo in your setup script. On the first line your are missing a `$`. The script should look as follows.

```
<?php
$installer=$this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE my_ibanner_banner ADD INDEX  banner_id");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE colorswatches ADD INDEX option_id");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE colorswatches ADD INDEX colorswatches_id ");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE color_relationship_product  ADD INDEX color_relationship_product");
$installer->endSetup();
```